# paymentaction=order creating "FAIL Error: 4003" from pdt

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I had an issue with paypal standard, payment data transfer (pdt). I received FAIL Error: 4003 so I changed the paypal button attribute paymentaction from order to authorization and received success. I also tried paymentaction=sale and leaving paymentaction off and both resulted in success.

The main issue is that paymentaction=order use to work... did something in paypal standard change?

Is there another way to retrieve a success by adapting the Return URL script?

The Unique Transaction ID is different between the paymentactions... when set to order it begins with an O-...

An easy way to test is just https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-synch&tx={Unique Transaction ID}&at={Identity Token}

If no one has an answer to this at least someone may find it useful.